# How do I patch NWN2?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I recently bought a legit copy of Neverwinter Nights 2 on sale at a bookstore.  Yes I know it's 11 years old now. I'd still like to be able to patch the game, but alas the site nwn2.com seems long gone. I checked archive.org and a few other places and even links on game cheats are gone.

How can I patch the game now that most of the resources and support for it seem to be missing?

Comment: Have you tried installing on Steam? They might have the latest version.

Comment: Are there legitimate no-CD patches?  It seems like a way to bypass the DRM.

Comment: +JMac I've removed that part of my question.

Comment: +Viper_Sb It's not on Steam.

Comment: Just curious, was it really cheap?   Cheaper than GOG.com @ 75% discount?

Comment: I paid $1 for it in the bargin bin at a used bookstore.  It is the gold edition and also came with the mask of the betrayer expansion and I think someone mistakenly put Company of Heroes in the box too. Can't get much cheaper than that. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## To the Vault!

[The Neverwinter Vault](https://neverwintervault.org/) may be useful to you; specifically their [**patches**](https://neverwintervault.org/patches) section.

Change the game drop-down to '*NwN2*' and patch drop-down to '*Obsidian*' (or '*All*') and it should bring up all the files you require to update the game from vanilla to a version that satisfies. I believe you need to run each file (i.e from 1.00788 to 1.02809, etc.) individually as you require to update the game.

Alternatively, there is also an additional, optional [NwN2 Patcher by tnt220](https://neverwintervault.org/patch/nwn2/english/nwn2-patcher-tnt220) which would let you update the game offline, but requires the patch files (linked above) to be obtained prior to using the tool. This appears to be an automated process which could reduce some of the monotony of running each patch individually.